# Minimum of Overlapping Intervals

Tags: algorithms

we have a 1-d space [1...N]. We are given M intervals of the form [L(i), R(i), C(i)] for 1 <= i <= M, where L(i) is the left most point, R(i) the rightmost and C(i) the value of that interval .

Now, for each point from 1 to N of the 1-d space, we need to find if the point lies in some interval. If it does, then we need to find the interval with the minimum value.

I have a very simple O((N + M)logM) algorithm. Basically, we maintain a multiset. The best value for point i is the minimum of the multiset. 
We also find out if the point lies in some interval by using two auxiliary vectors of cost values. First one is for the cost values that are to be inserted in the multiset, second one is for the cost values that are to be removed. We use multiset as cost values can be duplicate.

Total complexity =>

N * logM(for each point, we need to find minimum from multiset, and it can be done in logM, so N * logM)

+
MlogM(M values to be inserted in total for total of M intervals)

+
MlogM(M values to be removed in total for total of M intervals)

=> NlogM + 2MlogM
=> (N + M)logM

So, I am hoping for a better algorithm (N + M) maybe. So, is there some cool idea / algorithm for this problem?

[image]

Comment: Hint:  Redraw your diagram with the intervals sorted ascending by their left ends and descending by length (R-L) and an algorithm may become plain.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I have got a new idea using a priority queue(min heap) of a pair of integers(pair<int, int>, where first is the cost value of interval and second is the deadline). Now we move from each point 1 to N in ascending order and add intervals that start at point i to the min heap. Then, to find minimum, we get the min element from heap. If i point crosses the farthest point of interval, we skip and continue till we get an okay element. Is your idea same as this or even more efficient? How does sorting by left end and length helps here?

Comment: I'll see if I can whip up an answer.  (Might not happen today.)

Comment: Are you familiar with [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)?